# Getting Exception When trying to cast Document to Custom class?

Tags: java, c#, spring, wcf

i have created a java spring maven application in that i  have include a C# WCF service as web service client. for me able access wcf methods in my code now problem is wcf service contain one method name as postLeadsTest(PostLeadsLeadRequestXML doc, userID); i callthis method in this way

```
LMSLeadLocator lms=new LMSLeadLocator();
ILead llms =lms.getBasicHttpBinding_ILead();
llms.intiallizeconnection("SparkLMS");
Object los;
PostLeadsLeadRequestXML leadRequestXML = (PostLeadsLeadRequestXML)doc;
llms.postLeads(leadRequestXML, userID)
```

in that time i am getting an exception

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl cannot be cast to
>   org.tempuri.PostLeadsLeadRequestXML

please help to solve this issue  and then PostLeadsLeadRequestXML class contain this code

```
 /**
 * PostLeadsLeadRequestXML.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis 1.4 Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT) WSDL2Java emitter.
 */

package org.tempuri;

public class PostLeadsLeadRequestXML  implements java.io.Serializable, org.apache.axis.encoding.AnyContentType, org.apache.axis.encoding.MixedContentType {
    private org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement [] _any;
    public PostLeadsLeadRequestXML() {
    }

    public PostLeadsLeadRequestXML(
           org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement [] _any) {
           this._any = _any;
    }


    /**
     * Gets the _any value for this PostLeadsLeadRequestXML.
     * 
     * @return _any
     */
    public org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement [] get_any() {
        return _any;
    }


    /**
     * Sets the _any value for this PostLeadsLeadRequestXML.
     * 
     * @param _any
     */
    public void set_any(org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement [] _any) {
        this._any = _any;
    }

    private java.lang.Object __equalsCalc = null;
    public synchronized boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof PostLeadsLeadRequestXML)) return false;
        PostLeadsLeadRequestXML other = (PostLeadsLeadRequestXML) obj;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (__equalsCalc != null) {
            return (__equalsCalc == obj);
        }
        __equalsCalc = obj;
        boolean _equals;
        _equals = true && 
            ((this._any==null && other.get_any()==null) || 
             (this._any!=null &&
              java.util.Arrays.equals(this._any, other.get_any())));
        __equalsCalc = null;
        return _equals;
    }

    private boolean __hashCodeCalc = false;
    public synchronized int hashCode() {
        if (__hashCodeCalc) {
            return 0;
        }
        __hashCodeCalc = true;
        int _hashCode = 1;
        if (get_any() != null) {
            for (int i=0;
                 i<java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(get_any());
                 i++) {
                java.lang.Object obj = java.lang.reflect.Array.get(get_any(), i);
                if (obj != null &&
                    !obj.getClass().isArray()) {
                    _hashCode += obj.hashCode();
                }
            }
        }
        __hashCodeCalc = false;
        return _hashCode;
    }

    // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(PostLeadsLeadRequestXML.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://tempuri.org/", ">>PostLeads>leadRequestXML"));
    }

    /**
     * Return type metadata object
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Serializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Deserializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

}
```

Note: this auto generated web service client code